# How to return Time using a 2-D array (Java)?

Tags: java, arrays, modulo

**EDIT:**

[image: I dont know how to implement the return statement]

*Unfortunately I dont know how to implement the return statement. Which is the problem (MPFP Book 2005)*

This program is designed to add time onto time. E.g. add 1 hour and 40 minutes to 2:20 ~ gives 4:00 using a conventional 2-D array that **stores the new time**.

My issue is that I do not know how to append integers 'newminutes' and 'newhours' onto the 2-D array as well as return it properly in standard time form.

```
public class AddingTime {

    private static int [] [] nativeClockAdd (int oldHours,int oldMinutes,int addHours,int addMinutes)
    {
        int newMinutes = 0, newHours = 0;

        int[][] time = new int [newMinutes] [newHours]; // return a time.   


    newMinutes = oldMinutes + addMinutes;

    while (newMinutes > 60) // subtract 60 minutes, add an hour
    {
    newMinutes -= 60;
    addHours += 1;
    }
    newHours = oldHours + addHours;

    while (newHours > 12)
    {
    newHours -= 12; 
    }   
    return time;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println (nativeClockAdd(4,5,7,8));

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this structure defined in some kind of assignment or can it be changed?

Comment: @Gamb I am not sure how to follow the pseudo code- which is my concern. Now should I re-post with current edit and give Justin best answer or wait for some help on the issue?

Comment: If Justin helped you solve the problem, accept and finish the assignment. If not, edit and wait.

Comment: You can solve programming puzzles any way you'd like. You don't have to translate this pseudo code line for line. Read over the speudocode to understand what it is you should be doing, and then use your abilities to carry out the operations in an efficient, sensible way. The pseudocode here is actually *very* bad, using loops to do subtraction and addition is ridiculous. Just use multiplication and division. Is the next page of the book an exercise to make this code better?

Comment: @JustinDanielson Next page uses the modulus operator ~ so yes. However it also returns it as an array also which is the part that is confusing me..

Comment: @BDillan I'm late, sorry, but you should follow the pseudocode as you were doing and, if the next part uses the modulus operator, do it like Justin correctly points at. I believe this kind of assignments are intended to give you a starting code and then showing you how to tune it up to learn mutliple ways to attack a problem. In the end, you'll always come up with a personal winner and that defines you as a coder.

Comment: I think returning an array is their way of painfully introducing you to classes. Once you create a simple class, you can initialize it and return the instance of that class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (newMinutes > 60) // subtract 60 minutes, add an hour
{
    newMinutes -= 60;
    addHours += 1;
}
newHours = oldHours + addHours;

while (newHours > 12)
{
    newHours -= 12; 
}
```

This is not good at all. Read up on the modulus operator. All those loops can be done in a handful of lines.

```
newMinutes = oldMinutes + addMinutes;           //add minutes
newHours = oldHours + addHours + newMinutes/60; //int truncation is ok, 61/60 = 1
newHours = newHours % 12; //convert to 12hr format
if(newHours == 0) { //12 % 12 is 0, set it back to 12 if that's the case
    newHours = 12;
}
```

If you want to do this more easily, create a class for Time which simply is a pair of integers for hours and minutes. You can return this object rather than a weird int[2].

```
class MyTime {
    private int minutes;
    private int hours;
    //Make this public if you think you'll need it.
    private MyTime(int h, int m) {
       this.hours = h;
       this.minutes = m;
    }

    public int getMinutes() { return minutes; }
    public int getHours() { return hours; }

    public static MyTime AddTime(int h, int m, int elapsedHours, int elapsedMinutes) {
        m += elapsedMinutes;         //add minutes
        h += elapsedHours + (m/60);  //add hours + the possible hour from minutes. integer truncation here is good. 61/60 = 1
        m = m%60;                    //get rid of excess minutes. 60 becomes 0, 61 becomes 1, etc...
        return new MyTime(h, m);
    }

    //I'm not sure if this will compile.
    /*
    public static int[2] AddTimeWeird(int h, int m, int elapsedHours, int elapsedMinutes) {
        MyTime myTime = AddTime(h, m, elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes);
        int time[] = new int[2];
        time[0] = myTime.getHours();
        time[1] = myTime.getMinutes();
        return time;
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class which represents time, and store an array of those instead of an array of primitives. I'd use a double in this time class, and store it internally in some predefined unit. Then, create methods which return it in other units, like so:

```
public class Time{
    private double minutes;
    public double getHours(){
        return this.minutes/60;
    }
    public double getMinutes(){
        return this.minutes;
    }
    public void add(Time time){
        this.minutes+=time.minutes;
    }
    //etc
}
```